# Where should I ask questions about using software?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask questions about using software? For example:

```
How do I convert a .gif picture into a .png picture using XYZ software?
How do you change the window; workspace layout in XYZ software?
How do you import a document from ABC software into XYZ software?
Where is the "Save" button in XYZ software?
```

I know I can't use [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), as it's not relating to programming, and I can't use [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) as it is not relating to the installation of software or anything to do with hardware.

To be specific, I'm looking for help on using [Source Filmmaker](http://www.sourcefilmmaker.com), both in the departments of making scripts and basic usage/techniques.

---

Yes, I know I can ask script-related questions on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com), but where do I ask questions about usage of the software?

Comment: You could possibly use Software Recommendations

Comment: @Omen No, it is not a recommendation and SR has very strict rules.

Comment: We also have separate sites for some specific software like [Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user80551, and I have used the site before. But it doesn't cover Source Filmmaker. Also,  I'm not trying to convert .obj(s) into .mdl(s) through blender.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure why you got the impression that a question about how to use software couldn't fit on Super User as its on-topic Help Page says:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

> - computer hardware,
> - **computer software**, or
> - personal and home computer networking

> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

SourceFilmMaker is a software product that you need to install and use on your local box so it should fit on SU. It requires [Steam](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/steam) and that has a tag on Super User as well.

One other alternative you might investigate is [Video](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as their on-topic page states:

> you have a question about

> - broadcast, film or location recording techniques

- Shooting, editing, color grading, and distribution
- Post-production techniques
- Asset management, media, and file formats
- **installation, configuration, and operation of hardware or software related to these topics**

> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

I found those by performing a Stack Exchange [wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=sourcefilmmaker).

For either site, be sure you search and/or ask on their Meta first, take their tour and study the Help center to learn the specific requirements for questions on the target site. When in doubt, ask on the site specific meta first.