# Where should I post a question regarding Source Filmmaker?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Source Filmmaker is a animation software that allows uses to import any assets for the Source Engine and then animate it. (But not sculpt/use models from scratch; that's the Hammer tool)
However, I'm not sure where to put it; StackOverflow is for web development and SuperUser isn't meant for filmmaking... While video.SE doesn't cover the usage of the programs. I'm not making a video; I'm trying to make a map work.

**(No, this isn't a game, even though it uses a game engine)**, so - It doesn't go onto Gaming.SE

Also, there aren't tags (`source-filmmaker`) for it on any of them.

Where would I ask a question like:

---

## How do I properly run a DoTA 2 map [in Source Filmmaker]?

I've imported and mounted the DoTA 2 assets. However, when I try to open the DoTA 2 map, it crashes. However, I can open any other model (ie. Gear, Couriers, Heroes etc.) and use it in any other map.

Comment: [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240549/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-using-software/240550#240550) pretty much answers the question.